# Solving $5+2\cos(3\theta-\frac{\pi}{4})=6$ with $-\pi\leq\theta<\pi$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Solve: $$5 + 2 \cos \left(3 \theta - \frac{\pi}{4} \right) = 6,\quad -\pi \leq \theta < \pi$$

I am learning trigonometry and I have been having trouble with the following question (and questions like these). I solved it on my own, yielding many but all incorrect answers.

Here's what I did:

1. I solved $\cos(3\theta - \frac{\pi}{4}) = 0.5$, getting $\frac{\pi}{3}$ (60 degrees).
2. I then drew a unit circle and tried to figure out where cos would be positive
3. I got $\theta = 1.134, -1.134, -3.23, 0.960, -2.53$

I would greatly appreciate a detailed explanation. I clearly have gaps in my trig knowledge.

Edit: Tried to explain what I did, but am a beginner and confused, so can't do any better explaining.

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). If you can show us exactly what you tried (what steps did you try?), we will be more willing to help you.

Comment: Can you show us your attempts? Perhaps it's only one step away from being correct :)

Comment: Here is how to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/29979#29979).

Comment: I tried to do that, thank you.

Comment: I assume $30$ is meant to be $3\theta$.

Comment: yes - I'll try to fix it (edit: thank you!)

Comment: It's probably best to leave $\theta$ expressed in terms of $\pi$, and don't forget that the answer has to be between $-\pi$ and $+\pi$.

Comment: An immensely useful equation to use in all trigonometric equations like this is (for cosine)
$$
\cos x = \cos y \qquad \Leftrightarrow \qquad x = \pm y  + n2\pi, \qquad n \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
In this case you would start with
$$
\cos \left(\underbrace{3 \theta - \frac{\pi}{4}}_{=x} \right) = \frac{1}{2} = \cos \underbrace{\frac{\pi}{3}}_{=y}
$$
leading to
$$
3 \theta - \frac{\pi}{4} = \ldots
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions already shown that will work perfectly well.
So I'll try something a little different, using the unit circle for visualization.

To solve $\cos(\alpha) = \frac12$ using the unit circle, we draw a vertical line at $x = \frac12$ and intersect the circle in two points:

[image]

Each point is located at a particular angle. As usual there are infinitely many angles for each point depending on whether you go counterclockwise or clockwise and how many times you go around the circle before stopping, but representative angles are
$$ \alpha_A = \frac\pi3, \quad \alpha_B = -\frac\pi3. $$

But of course we're not trying to solve $\cos(\alpha) = \frac12$;
we need to solve $\cos\left(3\theta - \frac\pi4\right) = \frac12$.
But let's just concentrate on the $3\theta$ part and deal with $\frac\pi4$ later.

If we were trying to solve for $\phi$ in $\cos(3\phi) = \frac12$,
one solution is just to take $\frac13$ of one of the solutions of
$\cos(\alpha) = \frac12$.
That is, instead of identifying point $A$ at angle
$\alpha_A = \frac\pi3,$ we identify point $A_1$ at angle
$\phi_{A1} = \frac13 \alpha_A = \frac13\left(\frac\pi3\right) = \frac\pi9,$ as shown below.

[image]

So $\cos(3\phi_{A1}) = \cos\left(3\times\frac\pi9\right)
 = \cos\left(\frac\pi3\right) = \frac12$ as desired.

But we have to remember that $A$ could also be reached by angles such as
$\frac\pi3 + 2\pi,$ $\frac\pi3 - 2\pi,$ and so forth.
And note that you only have to add $\frac{2\pi}3$ to $\phi$ in order to add
$2\pi$ to $3\phi.$ That is,

\begin{align}
3\left(\frac\pi9 + \frac{2\pi}3\right) &= \frac\pi3 + 2\pi, \\
3\left(\frac\pi9 - \frac{2\pi}3\right) &= \frac\pi3 - 2\pi. \\
\end{align}

At angles $\frac\pi9 + \frac{2\pi}3$ and $\frac\pi9 - \frac{2\pi}3$
we have two more points, $A_2$ and $A_3$:

[image]

We could also try angles such as $\frac\pi9 + \frac{4\pi}3$ and
$\frac\pi9 - \frac{4\pi}3$, since $3\times\frac{4\pi}3 = 4\pi,$
but notice that $\frac\pi9 + \frac{4\pi}3$ identifies the same point as
$\frac\pi9 - \frac{2\pi}3$, so it would not add anything to the diagram.

Just as we did for point $A$, we can do for point $B$: one solution for
$\cos(3\phi) = \frac12$ is
$\phi_{B1} = \frac13 \alpha_B = \frac13\left(-\frac\pi3\right) = -\frac\pi9,$
giving point $B_1$ in the figure below;
and again we also get solutions by adding or subtracting $\frac{2\pi}3,$
giving points $B_2$ and $B_3.$

[image]

So that's six points on the unit circle whose angles solve $\cos(3\phi) = \frac12.$
There are other angles that solve the equation but each one lands at one of these same six points, so these six points represent all solutions.
Let's show them all together:

[image]

Now is a good time to recall that we're actually trying to solve
$\cos\left(3\theta - \frac\pi4\right) = \frac12$ and not
$\cos(3\phi) = \frac12$.
It's helpful to rewrite the original equation in the form
$$\cos\left(3\left(\theta - \frac\pi{12}\right)\right) = \frac12,$$
because that tells us that for each solution for $\theta$ we just need to add
$\frac\pi{12}$ to one of the solutions for $\phi$ (in order to get back to $\phi$ after we subtract $\frac\pi{12}$).
That is, all the solutions get rotated counterclockwise by the angle $\frac\pi{12}$.

[image]

Those are all the points that can be identified by angle $\theta$ where
$\cos\left(3\theta - \frac\pi4\right) = \frac12$.
We just have to identify angles for each one such that $-\pi \leq \theta < \pi.$
We can reconstruct the angles by following the steps of the construction of these six points, that is, identifying angles $\frac\pi9$ and $\frac\pi9$, getting three angles from each of these (the original angle and the angle plus or minus $\frac{2\pi}3$),
and adding $\frac\pi{12}$ to every angle:

\begin{align}
\theta_{A1} &= \frac\pi9 + \frac\pi{12} &
\theta_{B1} &= -\frac\pi9 + \frac\pi{12} \\
\theta_{A2} &= \frac\pi9 + \frac{2\pi}3 + \frac\pi{12} &
\theta_{B2} &= -\frac\pi9 + \frac{2\pi}3 + \frac\pi{12} \\
\theta_{A3} &= \frac\pi9 - \frac{2\pi}3 + \frac\pi{12} &
\theta_{B3} &= -\frac\pi9 - \frac{2\pi}3 + \frac\pi{12}.
\end{align}

Now (to make the answer more concise) we just want to work out what each of these angles is in simpler terms by finding a common denominator for all the fractions and combining them. For example, $$\frac\pi9 + \frac\pi{12} = \frac{7\pi}{36}.$$
Fortunately, it turns out all the angles in the list end up between
$-\pi$ and $\pi,$ but if some of them had fallen outside that range, we would just have had to add or subtract multiples of $2\pi$ to bring them back into the desired range.

---

If you look carefully, you may notice that the steps taken in this answer are the exact same steps taken in several other answers; the only difference is that here they have been plotted on the unit circle.

Answer (score 2):

$5+2\cos\Big(3\theta-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\Big)=6\Rightarrow \cos\Big(3\theta-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\Big)=\dfrac{1}{2}$

$-\pi\leq\theta\leq\pi\Rightarrow \dfrac{-13\pi}{4}\leq3\theta-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\leq\dfrac{11\pi}{4}$

$\cos\Big(3\theta-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\Big)=\dfrac{1}{2}\Rightarrow 3\theta-\dfrac{\pi}{4}=\dfrac{-7\pi}{3},\dfrac{-5\pi}{3},\dfrac{-\pi}{3},\dfrac{\pi}{3},\dfrac{5\pi}{3},\dfrac{7\pi}{3}$

[image]

Thus $\theta=\dfrac{-25\pi}{36},\dfrac{-17\pi}{36},\dfrac{-\pi}{36},\dfrac{7\pi}{36},\dfrac{23\pi}{36},\dfrac{31\pi}{36}$

These are the six solutions within the domain. Does this solve your question?

Comment: Right. Beginning to make some sense. Can you tell me exactly how you got  $3\theta−\pi4=−7\pi3,−5\pi3,−\pi3,\pi3,5\pi3,7\pi3$? Did you add $2\pi$ to $\pi/3$?

Comment: $3\theta - \pi/4$ must be in the domain I mentioned in the answer. I have just written down the values in the domain where it is equal to $1/2$

Comment: Yes. How did you get those values? Do we use the CAST method? What do we do to get every value every time?

Comment: I myself have used the graphical method. You may use any method you desire.

Answer (score 2):

It can be simpler, if you search the general solutions first.

You have to know how to solve basic equations in cos (there are also basic equations with $\sin$ and $\tan$):
$$\cos\alpha=\cos\beta\iff \alpha\equiv\pm\beta\mod 2\pi.$$
So in the present case, you have
\begin{align}
&\phantom{{}\iff{}}\cos\Bigl(3\theta-\frac\pi 4\Bigr)=\frac12=\cos\frac\pi3\iff 3\theta-\frac\pi 4\equiv\pm\frac\pi3\mod 2\pi\\ &\iff3\theta\equiv\frac\pi 4\pm\frac\pi3\mod 2\pi \iff 3\theta\equiv -\frac\pi{12},\frac{7\pi}{12}\mod 2\pi \\ &\iff \theta\equiv -\frac\pi{36},\frac{7\pi}{36}\mod \frac{2\pi}3
\end{align}
There remains to select the solutions which are in $[-\pi,\pi)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=3\theta-\frac{\pi}{4}$ and since we have $-\pi \leq \theta <\pi,$ then $-3\pi \leq 3\theta <3 \pi$ so that $-\frac{13}{4}\pi\leq3\theta-\frac{\pi}{4}<\frac{11}{4}\pi.$ So we are looking for $x$ in the range $-\frac{13}{4}\pi\leq x<\frac{11}{4}\pi.$

Now $$5+2\cos(x)=6 \implies \cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}$$

For what values of $x$ is this true? Consider using the [CAST method](https://www.onlinemathlearning.com/trig-equations-cast.html#:%7E:text=What%20is%20the%20CAST%20diagram,values%20for%20sin%20are%20positive.) or draw the $\cos$ function.

> \begin{align}  \text{The required solutions are} \space x=\cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{2})+2n\pi =\frac{\pi}{3}+2n\pi \space \text{and} \\ x=-\cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{2})+2n\pi  =-\frac{\pi}{3}+2n\pi \space \text{for $n\in\mathbb Z$}. \space \text{Now you have to find which of these lie in the region $-\frac{13}{4}\pi\leq x<\frac{11}{4}\pi$}.  \end{align}

> \begin{align} \text{We have $x=-\frac{7}{3}\pi,-\frac{5}{3}\pi,-\frac{1}{3}\pi,\frac{1}{3}\pi,\frac{5}{3}\pi\space \text{and} \space \frac{7}{3}\pi.$} \space \text{Now convert them back using $\theta=\frac{1}{3}(x+\frac{\pi}{4})$ since you want $\theta$ and not $x$.} \end{align}

Answer (score 1):

From $\cos(3 \theta - \pi/4) = 0.5$, you actually get:

$$\cos^{-1} \left( \cos(3 \theta - \pi/4) \right) = \cos^{-1} (0.5)$$
$$\Rightarrow 3 \theta - \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{3}, -\frac{\pi}{3}$$

Because $\cos(-x) = \cos(x)$, both $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $-\frac{\pi}{3}$ are valid values of $\cos^{-1} (0.5)$. You can alternatively get this result through using a CAST diagram or other sign diagram.

Solve these equations to find the value of $\theta$. Since $\cos(x) = \cos(x + 2 \pi) = \cos(x - 2 \pi)$ by periodicity, when you factor out a $3$ inside the $\cos$, $\cos(3(x/3)) = \cos(3(x/3 + 2\pi/3))$$ = \cos(3(x/3 - 2\pi/3))$. Substituting $\theta = x/3$, you will find that you need to add or subtract multiples of $(2/3) \pi$ to get the other values of $\theta$, instead of multiples of $2 \pi$. Rememebr to exclude the values that lie outside the domain $-\pi ≤ \theta < \pi$.

There are $6$ solutions in the given domain. Can you find them all (in terms of $\pi$)?

Comment: I see. So $\cos(x) = cos(-x)$, meaning that the same angle (x-value) with satisfy both equations for the same y-value. That means $\cos(x)=cos(x+2π)=cos(x−2π)$ because cos repeats after $2\pi$. Why did you factor out a 3? Can you elaborate where x/3 = $\theta$ comes from?

Comment: The key is to realise that this function has a period of $2 \pi/3$ instead of $2 \pi$ or any other number. Recall that the function transformation $f(ax)$ squishes the function if $a > 1$, and stretches it if $a < 1$. Therefore $\cos(3x)$ (the $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ does not stretch anything) squishes the $\text{cos}$ function by $2 \pi$ by $3$, so the period is $2 \pi / 3$.

Answer (score 1):

You should know these two points :

1. $\cos x=\cos(-x)$, i.e we always have two solutions for the next point:
2. $\cos x=a\Leftrightarrow x=\arccos(a)+2k\pi$, or, $x=-\arccos(a)+2k\pi$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}=\{...,-2,-1,0,1,2,...\}$.

Substitute $x$ by $3\theta-\pi/4$ and $a$ by $1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos(3\theta - \frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\cos(3\theta - \frac{\pi}{4})=\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}) \text{ or} \cos(3\theta - \frac{\pi}{4})=\cos(\frac{-\pi}{3})$$
$$3\theta - \frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{3} \text{ or } 3\theta - \frac{\pi}{4}=-\frac{\pi}{3}$$
$$3\theta = \frac{7\pi}{12} \text{ or } 3\theta =\frac{-\pi}{12}$$
$$\theta = \frac{7\pi}{36} \text{ or } \theta =\frac{-\pi}{36}$$

Note that with $\theta = \frac{7\pi}{36}$ we can find any other angle in given domain